# How to draw auxiliary line and point label?

Tags: plotting, labeling

I wan to draw the ECC and the auxiliary line. I tried this:

`ECCPlot[a_, b_, c_, d_]:=ContourPlot[{y^2  ==  a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d,y == x + 1, (x + 1)^2 ==  a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d }, {x,-5,5}, {y, -5, 5}, Axes -> True,Frame -> False, Mesh -> {{0.}}]`

and what I want is like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
Epilog -> Line[{{-2, 4}, {3, 8}}]
```

or whatever you want the line to be.